# Symfony 4 migration entity form validation using validation.yaml

Tags: php, symfony, validation

We are migrating a fairly large Symfony 3.4 application to 4.3 using flex. The validation rules for our entities reside in a separate validation.yaml. There are a lot of entities and a lot more rules so we'd rather not switch to annotations at this time.

[The documentation here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/validator/resources.html) describes how to use the validator with a separate yaml file, this is working fine in the rare cases where we use the validator directly, however most validation is done when forms are submitted like so:

```
$userForm->handleRequest($request);
if ($userForm->isSubmitted() && $userForm->isValid()) {
   // persist form data
}
```

Here the rules in validation.yml are ignored so most of our forms aren't validated anymore.

All configuration for the validator is this rule in /config/packages/validator.yaml

```
framework:
    validation:
        email_validation_mode: html5
```

And this rule in /config/packages/framework.yaml

```
framework:
    // other stuff
    validation: { enabled: true }
```

We've searched the docs and the web extensively to find a way to get validation in forms to work again but could't find or failed to understand how to do it. So the question is:

How do we get form validation to work using entity validation rules in a seperate yaml file?

Edit:

As asked, here is the content of our config/validator/validation.yaml (the first three entities, this file is huge. The mangled indentation is the stackoverflow codeblock, not so in our file, I'll try to tidy it up a little)

```
AppBundle\Entity\TaxSetting:
    properties:
        tarif:
            - NotBlank:
                  message: 'tax.tarif.empty'
            - Range:
                  min: 0
                  max: 100
                  minMessage: 'tax.tarif.too_low'
                  maxMessage: 'tax.tarif.too_high'
        fiscalDifference:
            - NotBlank:
                  message: 'tax.fiscaldifference.empty'
            - Range:
                  min: -2147483646
                  max: 2147483646
                  minMessage: 'tax.fiscaldifference.too_low'
                  maxMessage: 'tax.fiscaldifference.too_high'
 AppBundle\Entity\AdministrationUser:
     properties:
         user:
            - NotBlank:
                 message: 'administrationuser.user.empty'
         administration:
             - NotBlank:
                 message: 'administrationuser.administration.empty'
AppBundle\Entity\AdministrationUserGroup:
    properties:
        userGroup:
            - NotBlank:
                   message: 'administrationusergroup.usergroup.empty'
        administration:
            - NotBlank:
                message:'administrationusergroup.administration.empty'
```

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#getters seems to suggest the validation should be defined in config/validator/validation.yaml - extension might matter, have you checked it's exactly at that path?

Comment: @Jakumi I've checked again and the path is indeed (from root folder) config/validator/validation.yaml

Comment: Can you please post contents of `config/validator/validation.yaml`?

Comment: @ArleighHix see edit

Comment: I actually wonder, if the framework.yaml and validator.yaml might override each other and not be merged as assumed. can you try just putting the content from the validator.yaml into the framework.yaml (since the validator.yaml is almost empty) and remove the validator.yaml.

Comment: @Jakumi I've tried, but it had no effect

Comment: new theory as answer.

Comment: reading through the framework bundle, actually all y(a)ml files in config/validator should be evaluated automatically either way ........ can you check your `bin/console debug:configuration framework` output? maybe the frameworkbundle is not even enabled ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem:

We were following [SymfonyCasts migration guide](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony4-upgrade) which has as one of the final steps a namespace move from \AppBundle to \App, we even did a global search in the /src directory for any remaining mentions of 'AppBundle' but it never occurred to us to do the same in the config directory as all the config was either new or moved by hand, or so we thought...

As you can see in the excerpt form config/validator/validation.yaml it still uses the AppBundle namespace, causing validation to fail silently as it is still perfectly valid, it just refers to different classes. I guess my mind is just so used to seeing AppBundle\ prefixed to everything that it just didn't register.

Thanks for your time and input everyone, and sorry for not realizing this in hindsight rather obvious problem.